# Stashed Activity means activity object does not exist?

Tags: android, lifecycle

[image]

I was looking at this page from "Android Programming" by big nerd ranch, and I was confused by the sentence beneath. It states that "when the activity is stashed, an activity object does not exist." This is confusing to me because when I open an app and press the home button, onPause() is called and the activity reaches a "Paused" state with its activity stashed in the OS, as shown in the figure. It must be still running in the background because onDestroy() is not called when I press the home button. In fact, when I open my task manager, I can see how the activity looked like when I pressed the Home button. What exactly do they mean by "activity object does not exist?" when it is clearly on paused state in the background?

Comment: I think that the salient point here is the last sentence, "The OS can reanimate the activity using the activity record when it needs to."  Probably, the `Activity` object is no longer valid, but components inside the activity, specifically the `Parcelable` bits are stored by the OS.  When the app is resumed, the OS can build the activity back up from parcelable data. Android might also free up resources while your app is in the background as it sees fit, which ultimately calls `onDestroy`.

Answer (score 0):

THeir documentation looks to be a bit wrong and confusing.  The official Android documentation doesn't talk about a "stashed" state, it would be the block "App process killed" in the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.htm)

Basically, from the STOPPED state only, the OS may destroy your activity at any time.  If it does this, is will call onSaveInstanceState.  The Activity variable would then be invalid.  At any time, it may then recreate a new Activity and call onCreate then onRestoreInstanceState on it, passing in the Bundle you save previously, to recreate the activity.

Answer (score -1):

> This is confusing to me because when I open an app and press the home
>   button, onPause() is called and the activity reaches a "Paused" state
>   with its activity stashed in the OS, as shown in the figure.

I would not say that this is "stashed". Your activity is alive and well, just paused.

> It must be still running in the background because onDestroy() is not
>   called when I press the home button.

That's right. When you are hitting the home button you are saying to the OS "Hey I'm going somewhere else, but I'm not necessarily done with this activity."

If you instead hit the back button, then you'll see `onDestroy` called. Here you are saying to the OS "Ok I'm done with this activity, do with it what you want."

> What exactly do they mean by "activity object does not exist?" when it
>   is clearly on paused state in the background?

The stashed state is entered when the OS needs to destroy your activity without you "telling" it to do so (i.e. hitting back button). This happens when your device goes through a device configuration change. A classic example is rotation. This also happens if the OS needs to free up memory. In this case `onSaveInstanceState` will be called to capture the state of your activity in a `Bundle`. The stashed state is then the preservation of this `Bundle` and the class name of your activity. The actual Activity object is marked for garbage collection. Then given just the `Bundle` object and the class name of your activity, the OS can create a new instance of your activity if the user returns to it.

One take away is that you don't *have to* implement `onSaveInstanceState` yourself unless there is specific information you want preserved. Some components of the view hierarchy will automatically add information about themselves to the Bundle because the super `Activity.onSaveInstanceState` will still be called. From the docs:

> The default implementation takes care of most of the UI per-instance
>   state for you by calling onSaveInstanceState() on each view in the
>   hierarchy that has an id, and by saving the id of the currently
>   focused view (all of which is restored by the default implementation
>   of onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)). If you override this method to
>   save additional information not captured by each individual view, you
>   will likely want to call through to the default implementation,
>   otherwise be prepared to save all of the state of each view yourself.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

You can check the source here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#1371